# Codeigniter xss_clean issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

In codeigniter the `$this->input->post()` (with `xss_clean=true`)

gives this output

```
[removed]alert&#40;'Hello'&#41;[removed]
```

for this input string

```
<script>alert('Hello')</script>
```

I want the output without containing `[removed]`, i.e. `alert&#40;'Hello'&#41;`

Finally i ended up editing `system/core/security.php` file.

From

```
$str = preg_replace("#<(/*)(script|xss)(.*?)\>#si", '[removed]', $str);
```

To

```
$str = preg_replace("#<(/*)(script|xss)(.*?)\>#si", '', $str);
```

It does the job.

I'm just asking if there is any alternative way to do this without changing system files ?

Additionally ,

Should i use `codeigniter`'s `xss_clean` function ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try extend class from CI_Security and write new function:

`protected function _do_never_allowed($str)`

it will be more OOP way.

**EDIT:**

CodeIgniter allow you extend core classes. See this link:

[Extending CodeIgniter Security.php to enable logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589498/extending-codeigniter-security-php-to-enable-logging)

Answer (score 1):

You should NEVER edit the core files.

Instead, you should just extend the Security class, from the application.

Create a file called "MY_Security.php" within ./application/core and extend the Security class.